# LD_PRELOAD - possible to intercept primitive operators like + and -?

Tags: c, interception, ld-preload

Is it possible to intercept primitive operations (+,-,% etc.) like this one, with LD_PRELOAD?

```
int64_t endWhenNsec = startWhenNsec + gTimeLimitSec;
```

If not, any way to achieve something similar?

Comment: no, because usually, integer arithmetic operations aren't implemented as functions but as primitive instructions known to the CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Primitive operators are compiled directly to machine code.  There is no library involved, so preloading libraries cannot alter their behavior.  What a mess if it could!